# HSS Liquid Layout Issue: how to fill the entire browser

Tags: html, css

Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lmpswbxy/).

My page is a liquid layout. The side bars have constant width. The middle part will automatically change when browser is scaled.

My problems:

1. How to make the middle part and side bars' height to 100%. No matter how long the page is, the side bars will touch the bottom. These three parts will always fill the entire browser.
2. I want to fill the entire div with the image. In addition, the image will be automatically scaled when browser size is changed.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="left">
    1
</div>
<div id="right">
    1
</div>
<div id="main">
    <img src="img/1.jpg" />
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#left {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #000;
}

#right {
    float: right;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #000;
}

#main {
    margin: 0 110px 0 110px;
    background-color: #ccc;
}
```

Comment: i think you need this http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/Lmpswbxy/2/

Comment: Try this - http://jsfiddle.net/3a9jxf18/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly. You should set the height of the `<html>` and `<body>`element in the CSS to 100% then the `<div>`s should take up the whole page height.

### HTML:

```
<div id="left">
    1
</div>
<div id="right">
    1
</div>
<div id="main">
    <img src="img/1.jpg"/>
</div>
```

### CSS:

```
html {
    height: 100%; /*set to 100%*/
}
body{
    height: 100%; /*set to 100%*/
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#left{
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #000;
}
#right{
    float: right;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #000;
}
#main{
    height: 100%; /*set to 100%*/
    margin: 0 110px 0 110px;
    background-color: #ccc;
}
```

### Edited:

Apply this to your CSS then your image should take up the whole space of main `<div>`.
Notice: This will not preserve the image aspect ratio! 
(Thanks to aug, for pointing this out.)
To remove the vertical scroll bar just set the vertical-align attribute.
(Thanks to Mary Melody for this hint.)

```
#main img{
    vertical-align: middle; /*removes vertical scroll bar*/
    height: 100%;
    width:  100%;
}
```

I noticed that you could also add an `overflow:hidden;` to the `#main` CSS rule, like so:

```
#main{
    overflow: hidden; /*will removes vertical scroll bar too*/
}
```

[Here is a JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/o21y165v/9/)

Comment: To build on this, if I understand correctly, second part of the question where you want the image to fill the entire div, you simply need to add `#main img { width: 100%; height: 100%; }`. This will not maintain the aspect ratio of the image (unsure if this was a requirement)

Comment: @aug Oh I am embarrassed. How could I forget the second question? Thanks for pointing this out specially the aspect with the image ratio. I have edited the answer properly.

Comment: @Sascha you need to add `vertical-align` property to `#main img` to remove the vertical scroll bar - http://jsfiddle.net/qqsbtf6f/

Comment: @Mary Melody Thanks for this hint. I appended it to the answer. I also noticed that the `overflow: hidden;` rule used to reach the same effect.

Comment: I just want to say, u guy r freaking awesome!